# ASP.NET MVC3 - Dynamically adding an item to array on object

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-3

I'm working on a website where the user should be able to fill out a dynamic expanding form.

I would add a row with greyed out fields and when the user gives focus to one of those field the following javascript would add the line

```
<tr class="unSelected">
   <input name="id[]">
   <input name="blabla[]">
</tr>

$('.unSelected').focusin(function () {
  if ($(this).hasClass('unSelected')) {
    var row = $(this).clone(true);
    $(this).after(row);
    $(this).removeClass('unSelected');
  }
});
```

but how would one do this using razor and asp.net, as the objects wont be autogenerated then?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In ASP.NET MVC, if you have a model class like:

```
public class PageModel
{
    public Collection<RowItem> RowItems { get; set; }
}

public class RowItem
{
    public int Id {get;set;}
    public string MoreFields { get; set; }
}
```

And your javascript adds rows like so:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var currentRowIndex = 0;

    $(document).ready(function () {
        SetFocusEventForInputs('unSelected0');
    });

    function SetFocusEventForInputs(className) {
        var inputSelector = '.' + className;

        $(inputSelector).focusin(function () {
            AddNewRowTo(this);
            $(inputSelector).unbind('focusin').removeClass(className);
        });
    }

    function AddNewRowTo(sendingInputField) {
        currentRowIndex++;
        var className = 'unSelected' + currentRowIndex;
        var collectionNamePrefix = 'RowItems[' + currentRowIndex + '].';

        var idField = $('<input/>').attr('name', collectionNamePrefix + 'Id').attr('type', 'text').attr('class', className);
        var moreFields = $('<input/>').attr('name', collectionNamePrefix + 'MoreFields').attr('type', 'text').attr('class', className);

        var cell = $('<td></td>').append(idField).append(moreFields);
        var row = $('<tr></tr>').append(cell);

        $(sendingInputField).parents("tr").after(row);

        SetFocusEventForInputs(className);
    }
</script>
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <input name="RowItems[0].Id" type="text" class="unSelected0" />
            <input name="RowItems[0].MoreFields" type="text" class="unSelected0" />
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

The default model binder in MVC should resolve it just fine when it gets posted

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult YourPostActionHere(PageModel model)
{
    var count = model.RowItems.Count();
    etc...
}
```

Comment: I need the same solution, but when i remove one item in middle then RowItems index breaks, so only items before deleted row are posted successfully while all other skipping

Answer (score 0):

You can do it the same way, because in the code example above, you are using jQuery which is also supported (of course) with ASP.NET MVC.

Perhaps I don't understand you, but I don't see any PHP code in the code example above.

Comment: I might have been bad at explaining

In php i would do something like

$objWithArray = new objWithArray();
$i=0;
while (isset($_POST["id"][$i])) {
  $obj = new obj($_POST["id"][$i]);
  $objWithArray->addObj($obj);
  $i++;
}

But in asp.net it is possible to do a
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult method(ObjWithArray de) {
}

Which if the fields are named correctly will add them automatically.

Do you understand it now? :/

Answer (score 0):

what you want to do is a client side script that is not depend on PHP or Asp.Net so it does not matter what your code is written by. this should work in Asp.Net mvc too.

if you want to collect the new control data to use it in server side you can collect it by JavaScript and assign it in a hidden field that can be accessed in server side. you can use one hidden field by save the values in one string and separated by any delimiter.

Comment: Yeah, but then I would have to generate the objects server side by accessing the fields manually, my thought was to avoid that

Answer (score 0):

Are you possibly just missing the script tags?  Like the others said, javascript is platform independent.

```
<tr class="unSelected">
   <input name="id[]">
   <input name="blabla[]">
</tr>

<script src="/Scripts/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $().ready(function () {
        $('.unSelected').focusin(function () {
            if ($(this).hasClass('unSelected')) {
                var row = $(this).clone(true);
                $(this).after(row);
                $(this).removeClass('unSelected');
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```